# How to specify different tab widths for different languages?

Tags: neovim, plugin-coc, unix

I am using Neovim (v.0.8.0) along with nvim-lspconfig and neoclide/coc.
It is working pretty well.
The only problem being tab widths. If I am writing in say, Java or C, I use 4-space wide tabs, however if I am writing Javascript/Typescript, I prefer a 2-space wide tab.

How can I configure different tab sizes on a language basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to achieve that is to create for each type a file in: `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin`:

- `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/java.vim`
- `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/c.vim`
- `~/.config/nvimftplugin/javascript.vim`
- `~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/typscript.vim`

In each of the file you can set the corresponding settings you would like to use for the associated file type:

`~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/java.vim`

```
setlocal expandtab
setlocal tabstop = 4
setlocal shiftwidth = 4
```

`~/.config/nvim/ftplugin/typescript.vim`

```
setlocal expandtab
setlocal tabstop = 2
setlocal shiftwidth = 2
```

For this mechanism to work you need to have the following option set in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`:

```
filetype plugin on
```

If you need to override a setting that is set in the distribution `$VIM/ftplugin/filetype.vim` (e.g. `$VIM/ftplugin/java.vim`) you need to create the file in `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin` (e.g. `~/.config/nvim/after/ftplugin/java.vim`) instead and set the option there.

To have a clean solution your `filetype.vim` should also define the `b:undo_plugin` variable.
It is a vim command (or a list of vim command separated by `|`) executed by Vim when the user decides to switch the buffer to another filetype.

In our example we should do:

```
let b:undo_ftplugin = ''

let b:undo_ftplugin .= 'let &expandtab = ' . 
&expandtab

let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | '
let b:undo_ftplugin .= 'setlocal tabstop = ' . &tabstop
setlocal tabstop = 4

let b:undo_ftplugin .= ' | '
let b:undo_ftplugin .= 'setlocal shiftwidth = ' . &shiftwidth
setlocal shiftwidth = 4
```

It guarantee that when you switch the filetype you have a result that do not depend of the filetype you have 'visited'

But for `tabstop` the straightforward solution should work just fine.

An alternative is to have the following lines in your `~/.config/nvim/init.vim`

```
augroup javaindent
  autocmd FileType java setlocal expandtab
  autocmd FileType java setlocal tabstop=4
  autocmd FileType java setlocal shiftwidth=4
augroup END

augroup typescriptindent
  autocmd FileType typescript setlocal expandtab
  autocmd FileType typescript setlocal tabstop=2
  autocmd FileType typescript setlocal shiftwidth=2
augroup END
```

Remark: The answer is edited for Neovim on Linux or MacOs. For a solution on Vim the path have to be slightly adapted:

- `~/.config/nvim` will become `~/.vim` or `~/vimfiles` on Windows
- `~/.config/nvim/init.vim` will become `~/.vimrc` or `~/_vimrc` on Windows

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! Since I am using a UNix basedOS (MacOS), I put the `ftplugin` directory within ~/.vim instead of ~/vimfiles. Also since I am using neovim, the ftplugin should go in ~/.config/nvim/

Comment: You are right I'll update the solution to be more unix/neovim based

Comment: I default to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin` to make sure nothing else overwrites my values. Also, don't forget `b:undo_ftplugin`